# How to transform a txt file into a parquet file and load it into a hdfs table-pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have a text file that I am trying to convert to a parquet file and then load it into a hive table by write it to it's hdfs path. Everything runs but the table shows no values.

Here is my code:

```
#Create my table
spark.sql("create  external table if not exists table1 ( c0 string, c1 string, c2 string)  STORED AS parquet LOCATION 'hdfs://hadoop_data/hive/table1'")

hdfs="hdfs://hadoop_data/hive/table1/output.parquet"

#Read my data file
e=spark.read.text("/home/path/sample_txt_files/sample5.txt")

#Write it to hdfs table as a parquet file
e.write.parquet("hdfs")
```

Everything runs but when I check the contents of the table by select * from table1, no values are there:

[image: txt fi]

The content in the sample5.txt file goes like this:

```
ID,Name,Age
1,James,15
```

Content inside the .parqeut file
[image]

Any ideas or suggestion as to why no data is showing in the table?

Comment: Did you try to run the last command without the quotes? It seems you are passing literally "hdfs" instead of the string sdfs (the full path).

Comment: well the thing is, it's reading the parquet directory and not the succcess files inside the parquet folder. Do you know how to pass through that and read all the sucess parquet files?

Comment: and ya I tried without the quotes as well.

Comment: can you try this `e.write.parquet("hdfs://hadoop_data/hive/table1/output.parquet")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did u tried to set these parameters in **hive shell** as you are writing `hdfs://hadoop_data/hive/table1/output.parquet` directory but **table** is created on `hdfs://hadoop_data/hive/table1/`. As you are writing **`output.parquet`** nested directory.

```
SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=TRUE;
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=TRUE;
```

And then check are u able to see data from [hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767713/can-hive-recursively-descend-into-subdirectories-without-partitions-or-editing-h) table.

**`(or)`**

Try to insert data into `table directly` using **`.insertInto`** function.

```
e.write.format("parquet").insertInto("default.table1")
```

### UPDATE:

As you are reading text file even though if you have 3 columns spark reads as one column(value).

```
e=spark.read.text("/home/path/sample_txt_files/sample5.txt") //returns dataframe

f=e.withColumn("c0",split(col("value"),",")(0)).withColumn("c1",split(col("value"),",")(1)).withColumn("c2",split(col("value"),",")(2)).drop("value") //split the column and extract data

f.write.format("parquet").insertInto("default.table1")
```

In case if you have **`csv file (or) any other delimiter file`** use `spark.read.csv()` with options to read the file.

Comment: Have you ever face situation like in this below question. I was not able to reproduce it later. donnow for what reasons it was coming and sorted out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372962/filtering-a-spark-partitioned-table-is-not-working-in-pyspark/57357723#57357723

Comment: when i try to insert data into table directlry, it gives the error of target table has 3 columns but the inserted data has 1 column, but before formatting it to parquet it has three columns. Do you think once conveted to parquet, it changed the number of columns?

Comment: @JamesDavinport, please check the Updated answer.

Comment: @vikrantrana, Sorry.. I was not able to recreate the scenario with `spark 2.4` version. everything is working as expected..! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372962/filtering-a-spark-partitioned-table-is-not-working-in-pyspark/57357723#57357723

Comment: @ dhnsh, Thanks for checking it out for me. :-) Yeah even I am not able to reproduce it. I have had this problem last year and donnow how come it get resolved it self. I work on spark 2.3 though.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the underlying parquet data type comparing to your hive schema.
being said, the id, name, age are both string in hive table.
but when you write out the parquet, the data type of id and age might be int instead of string.